# How to wordwrap in gm for node?

Tags: node.js, gm

Found [GM](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) today need to include text in my image.  Is there a way to make sure my text wraps if it's width is longer than my image width?

Comment: Have you found an answer? I am facing same problem

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52739939/9271130. i gave example code.